# Tkinter, seemingly random spacing?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the following code.

```
    Label(pop, text = "Timesheet does not exist.").grid(row = 0)

    Label(pop, text = "Create Time sheet?").grid(row = 2, column = 0)

    y = Button(pop, text = "Yes").grid(row = 3, column = 1)
    n = Button(pop, text = "No").grid(row = 3, column = 0)
```

There's an odd space before the second label.[image: Screenshot]

Anyone have an explanation/solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing strange in there: the second button is in column 1, as you ordered it - while the other button, and the first two labels are on column 0. Column 1 should be to the left of column 0.

Use `colspan=2` as options to the construction of the `Label` objects, so that the phrases use both columns, and your second button does not show to the right of both.

Otherwise, just use the `pack`  layout manager instead of grid - since you don't seen to want a table like structure in small dialogs like this.

Comment: The button is centered in the column, but the width of the column is determined by the widest column in all the rows. Thats why you see the gap.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks for the help. I'm just gonna stick with pack for this dialog, but now I know. I guess I thought the default behavior would be to left align everything in a column.